# SQL Join when there are duplicate rows with different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to join these two tables, but it ends up showing duplicates values. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
+---------+-----------+------+------------+
| Table A |           |      |            |
+---------+-----------+------+------------+
| SeqID   | ID        | Part | PartNumber |
+---------+-----------+------+------------+
| 1       | ComputerA | Case | 111        |
+---------+-----------+------+------------+
| 2       | ComputerA | RAM  | 222        |
+---------+-----------+------+------------+
| 3       | ComputerA | RAM  | 333        |
+---------+-----------+------+------------+

+---------+-----------+------+----------+
| Table B |           |      |          |
+---------+-----------+------+----------+
| SeqID   | ID        | Part | SendDate |
+---------+-----------+------+----------+
| 412     | ComputerA | Case | 2001/3/5 |
+---------+-----------+------+----------+
| 413     | ComputerA | RAM  | 2001/3/5 |
+---------+-----------+------+----------+
| 414     | ComputerA | RAM  | 2001/3/5 |
+---------+-----------+------+----------+
```

Let's say we have these 2 tables.

I want result to be like below

```
+---------+-----------+------+------------+----------+
| Table C |           |      |            |          |
+---------+-----------+------+------------+----------+
| SeqID   | ID        | Part | PartNumber | SendDate |
+---------+-----------+------+------------+----------+
| 412     | ComputerA | Case | 111        | 2001/3/5 |
+---------+-----------+------+------------+----------+
| 413     | ComputerA | RAM  | 222        | 2001/3/5 |
+---------+-----------+------+------------+----------+
| 414     | ComputerA | RAM  | 333        | 2001/3/5 |
+---------+-----------+------+------------+----------+
```

, but when I run the code

```
   select b.seqid, b.id,b.part,a.partnumber,b.senddate from TableB b join TableA a on b.id = a.id and b.part = a.part group by b.seqid, b.id,b.part,a.partnumber,b.senddate order by b.seqid desc
```

I get below table

```
+---------+-----------+------+------------+----------+
| Table C |           |      |            |          |
+---------+-----------+------+------------+----------+
| SeqID   | ID        | Part | PartNumber | SendDate |
+---------+-----------+------+------------+----------+
| 412     | ComputerA | Case | 111        | 2001/3/5 |
+---------+-----------+------+------------+----------+
| 413     | ComputerA | RAM  | 222        | 2001/3/5 |
+---------+-----------+------+------------+----------+
| 413     | ComputerA | RAM  | 333        | 2001/3/5 |
+---------+-----------+------+------------+----------+
| 414     | ComputerA | RAM  | 222        | 2001/3/5 |
+---------+-----------+------+------------+----------+
| 414     | ComputerA | RAM  | 333        | 2001/3/5 |
+---------+-----------+------+------------+----------+
```

I see why this is happening and I think something is lacking on the condition part. Is there a way to achieve what I was expecting?

Comment: Depends on why you are expecting to have `SeqID` 413 join to `PartNumber` 222 and not 333.   What's the logic behind that?

Comment: your tableA and TableB seems have not a valid relation for return you expected  result  ..

Comment: An answer to 'why' this is happening?  You are joining to TABLE A using Part. Part 'RAM' which occurs in two records on TABLE A, once for part number 222 and again for part 333.  The join will by default show all the records for 'RAM'.  You then have to decide which part number you want, the first or last or ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve your desired result, based on your sample data, is to generate a ROW_NUMBER() column for each of the two tables, partitioned by `ID` and `Part` and ordered by `SeqID`, and then include those Row_Numbers in the JOIN condition.

Comment: I congratulate you on doing your own coding just based on the suggestion I gave.  : )

Answer (score 0):

Try this below-

```
SELECT B.SeqID,
A.ID,
A.Part,
A.PartNumber,
B.SendDate 
FROM Table_A A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SeqID) RN
    FROM Table_B
)B
ON A.SeqID = B.RN
```